# Do Crawlers get an extra activation, when all figures are in play and attack on Skinner has a 1?

Tags: zombicide

In [Zombicide Season 3: Rue Morgue](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/161866/zombicide-season-3-rue-morgue), you have Skinner zombies that turn to Crawlers, if the attack that would have killed them had a 1 in any of the dice.

However, if the Crawler can't be added, since all the figures are already in play, do the Crawlers get an extra activation as per the usual spawning rules? Or is this an exception, like splitting?

Answer (score 2):

The [rulebook of the Rue Morgue expansion](https://zombicide-2dc3.kxcdn.com/dl/rulebook-rue-morgue.pdf), at page 25, includes crawlers in the extra activation rule when running out of miniatures.

> The Zombicide Season 3: Rue Morgue box contains enough Zombies to invade a city. However, players may still run out of miniatures of the indicated type when required to place a Zombie  on  the  board  through  spawning **(including  Crawler spawning!)** or populating a building. In this case, the remaining Zombies  miniatures  are  placed  (if  there  are  any),  and then  all Zombies  of  the  indicated  type  immediately  resolve an extra Activation.

A few pages before, on page 12, the rulebook uses Crawler Spawning to refer the way Crawlers appear when killing Skinner zombies rolling "1s".

> 1 – Crawlers can appear each time Skinners are eliminated. After removing Skinner Zombies, whatever the type (Walker, Fatty,  or  Runner), and earning  experience points for the kill(s), add a Crawler for each “1” rolled on the attack roll. If you own Zombicide-themed dice, the “1” is replaced with a Zombie head. Read only the dice results: the +1 to dice roll Skills have no effect on **Crawler spawning**.

So crawler spawning refers to this way of adding figures. Anyway, when adding them through the bed card, extra activation rule activates too, as it's said in page 25, right above the "Running out of miniatures" section.

Comment: It's been a while, but I think the question was, does it count as a "spawning" if the Crawler comes from a dead Skinner.

Comment: I've edited my post to add a quotation which specifies what a Crawler spawning is, sorry for not including it before.

Comment: In addition, when not having enough miniatures does not active the extra action is specified in the rulebook too, and this only happens when splitting.

Comment: I belive we did find the same mention of spawning as you pointed out. I think we found the single mention of spawning to be a bit too vague to be sure. But thanks for the detailed answer. I think it's as good as one gets from the rulebook alone.